# Как обособить "значит"?

Tags: пунктуация

Как обособить (с одной стороны или с двух) "значит" в предложении:

> *Если ты сможешь ответить на все вопросы, значит ты сдал экзамен.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Если ты сможешь ответить на все вопросы, значит, ты сдал экзамен.***

А почему никто не читает Розенталя?

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

12) Слово ***значит***, если оно синонимично словам следовательно, стало быть, является вводным и выделяется запятыми...

Если слово ***значит*** находится **между придаточной и главной частями сложноподчиненного предложения и играет роль структурного элемента предложения, то оно выделяется запятыми:** *Если наступит весна, значит, будет тепло; Раз так упорно отстаивает свои взгляды, значит, чувствует свою правоту.*

Comment: вы объяснили всё понятно. Большое спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Надо обособить с обеих сторон, потому что в данном случае это часть двойного союза *если... значит,* близкая по значению к вводному слову:

> *Если ты сможешь ответить на все вопросы, значит, ты сдал экзамен.*

Запятая перед ним нужна в первую очередь ещё и потому, что закрывается придаточное с *если.*

Comment: Немного поправлю Вас: *„ЗНАЧИТ, вводное слово, **союз** и связка*... *Значение союза:* Соединяет предложения или части сложного предложения  (в том числе в составе двойного союза **если... значит** или «раз... значит»). Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения. Короче говоря, „Грамота” считает, что это может быть и вводным словом, и союзом, однако в данном случае это именно союз. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение! Интересно.

Comment: @Бот Ботович, Тогда в данном случае запятые не нужны?

Comment: @NaraMamedova: да нужны всё равно! Почитайте по ссылке.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, но ведь Бот Ботович написал, что это союз, а следовательно, не требует запятой...

Comment: @БотБотович, что вы скажете?

Comment: Да почему же не требует?! Вы по ссылке почитали? Вот: *сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, вы правы, до слова (значит) запятая нужна, а после?

Comment: @NaraMamedova, написано же: *союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от **последующей** части предложения.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, я поняла, но в вашем первоначальном ответе говорилось, что надо обособить с двух сторон, поэтому я переспросила. Не хотела вас сердить..

Comment: Да я не сержусь. :) И в нынешнем говорится то же самое. Поправка Бота не повлияла на расстановку знаков.

Answer (score 0):

Где-то я читал, что слово "значит" является вводным в значении "следовательно", как в данном случае. Если же "значит" употребляется в значении "обозначает", то запятые не нужны.Например: Любить Родину - значит защищать ее.

Comment: Это правило для простого предложения (тире между подлежащим и сказуемым). Розенталь: а) в положении между подлежащим и сказуемым слово значит служит средством связи главных членов предложения, перед ним ставится тире, а после него не ставится никакого знака: Бороться — значит победить; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122  Пункт 12.